# How to save and load rdd to remote hive using spark Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Now I am writing my data to rdbms using sqoop. So it store data to hdfs and then to rdbms. Is there any way to store rdd directly to Hive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write `RDD` to hive, One way to write `RDD` to hive is to convert RDD to Df and then saveTableAs() as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

import hiveContext.implicits._

//read data perform some transformation

val myDF = myRdd.toDF("column names")
```

Then you can create a table and dump the data

```
myDF.write.saveAsTable("tableName")

//with save mode 
myDF.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("tableName")
```

you can add save modes as above 
SaveModes are **Append,Ignore,Overwrite,ErrorIfExists**